# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: swiper-slide and swiper-container when using Swiper Element

Tags: vue.js, webpack, swiper.js, vue-loader

I'm using **[Swiper Element](https://swiperjs.com/element)** for slide effects in a Vue app, it works fine but I keep getting these two warnings,

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: swiper-slide
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: swiper-container
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

I installed the package and registered it just like the [docs](https://swiperjs.com/element#install--register-from-npm) recommended, I tried both at **main.js** and another time at **App.vue**, but it didn't make a difference.

```js
// import register function to register Swiper custom elements
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
// register Swiper custom elements
register();
```

after that, I tried to add it as a custom element manually (I think this is the job of the register function) using [instructions from Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-compileroptions), [Vue cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader) and [Vue Loader docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#compileroptions) like the following

**vue.config.js**

```js
...
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap((options) => {
        // modify the options...
        options.compilerOptions = {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => {
            return tag.startsWith('swiper');
          },
        };
        return options;
      });
  },
...
```

but still, nothing is different, this is my first time modifying the loader so I think I'm missing something In syntax it wasn't apparent how to modify the `isCustomElement` in **vue.config.js**

any help would be appreciated, my main goal is to remove the warnings so if you have any other approach I'd love to hear it.

**build Data**:

```json
    "swiper": "^10.3.1"
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
```

Comment: After you install the npm package you can immediately use it in a component.  The [documentation here](https://swiperjs.com/element#usage-with-vue) shows how.  I will just note a typo in the export default line you don't need `function ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked, I had to re-run serve the code works. :) that was fun